# How to "disable" CSS grid responsively?

Tags: css, css-grid

On mobile screens, I'd like to have two buttons laid out in a 3-column grid like that:

[image]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
}

.long-grid-item {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.short-grid-item {
  grid-column: 3/4;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="long-grid-item">
    <button>Long</button>
  </div>
  <div class="short-grid-item">
    <button>Short</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, on desktop screens, I'd like to "disable" the grid and have the buttons have a fixed width: 200px for the long button and 100px for the short one.

Is it possible to keep this HTML structure and just "disable" the grid functionality using media queries?

Comment: So change the display property and adjust your CSS accordingly. What is difficult here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set fix width of 100px for the column for devices width above 992px (or your desire width) with media query. I hope I understand your problem.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
}

.long-grid-item {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.short-grid-item {
  grid-column: 3/4;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="long-grid-item">
    <button>Long</button>
  </div>
  <div class="short-grid-item">
    <button>Short</button>
  </div>
</div>
```